# Cannot load a model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model, load

I failed to load a model from my controller

This is the controller file, article.php:

```
<?php
class Article extends CI_Controller {
function show($id) { //id'ye gore getir
    $this->load->model('articles_model');
    $parameter = $this->articles_model>getarticle($id);
    $this->my_template->build('article_view', $parameter);


}
}
?>
```

This is the model file, articles_model.php:

```
<?php
class Articles_model extends CI_Model {


function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

function Getarticle($id)  {
    parent::Model();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('articles', array('id' => $id));
    $data['articles'] = $query->result();
    return $data;
    $query->free_result();

}
}
?>
```

---

just to add, i even tried to load it from autoloader, still no chance, i assume something is wrong with the model, or the whole system broke.

up: the models loads without problems, if i put echo in __construct function, it works, however, i cannot call the getarticle function. geez

UP: I did it! according to http://grasshopperpebbles.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object/

i used
    $CI =& get_instance();
and called the function
    $CI->articles_model->getarticle($id) and it called the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be,

```
  $CI =&get_instance();

 $CI->load->model('articles_model');
    $parameter = $CI->articles_model>getarticle($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a parse error in the following line:

```
$parameter = $this->articles_model>getarticle($id);
```

It should be:

```
$parameter = $this->articles_model->getarticle($id);
```

Does that fix your problem?  If not, what error message are you seeing?

Comment: It didn't work, i've been searching the solution for hours, i'd feel ashamed if it did actually =).

the error is,

Message: Undefined property: Article::$articles_model

Filename: controllers/article.php


---
also,
var_dump($this->articles_model) returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Leif's answer is the right one.  Just to add one thing: you don't have to use the long variable name like `$this->articles_model` over and over, by using the [second parameter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading):

```
$this->load->model('articles_model','artm');
$parameter = $this->artm->getarticle($id);
```

Just a little faster to type, and can reduce typos like the one in your sample.